# How to intersect String from an array of values

Tags: arrays, groovy

I have one string and an array as below:

```
String matchingString='Test'
def a1=['Testing','Developer','DBA','Test']

def item = a1.contains(matchingString)

println item;
```

If there is a match found then from a1 i have to intersect matchingString and push the new result to an array.

Expected Result to be:

```
Result:['Testing','Developer','DBA']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to remove the element from your original list.

```
a1.removeElement(matchingString)
```

Groovy's [`removeElement`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeElement(java.lang.Object)) is basically the same as Java's [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) but is a little less ambiguous. The always excellent Mr. Haki has a [nice writeup](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/09/groovy-goodness-removing-elements-from.html) about removing elements from collections.

Comment: @dollelleri - I dont want to do it manually assert a1 == ['Testing','Developer','DBA'] because there can be 50 values.

Comment: @Studentlearner The assertion is just to show you that the element is no longer in `a1`.

Comment: `a1 - matchingString` does the same thing I think 